# Get array which is the result of invoking a function on each element of an object array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

What are my options for getting an array that is the result of invoking a function
on each element of a given (object) array?

What I do now is:

```
object_array # an array whose elements are objects
result_array=scipy.reshape( [o.f() for o in object_array.flat], object_array.shape )
```

My case is analogous to having `object_array[i,j]` be an instance of `scipy.stats.norm`, where the parameters of the distributions are different for different elements.
and `scipy.stats.norm.rvs()` is the `f()` that I want to call.  Note that the size of `object_array` may be quite large (up to about 1000x1000) so I'm concerned that this is sub-optimal in that I'm making at least one copy of the results when I call `reshape`.

Comment: Check out `np.vectorize` (or `scipy.vectorize` in your case)

Comment: To use vectorize you will need to store the .f() function call in a variable not attached to an instance of the class.  func_ref = TypeOfO.f then new_fun = scipy.vectorize(func_ref) then new_fun(object_array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach seems quite reasonable. I tried a better one using `np.nditer` but yours is still twice as fast:

```
import numpy as np
class Foo():
    def foo(self):
        return np.random.random()

a = np.empty((10,10), dtype=object)
for ind,v in np.ndenumerate(a):
    a[ind] = Foo()

def evaluate_and_reshape(a, shape):
    it = np.nditer( op    = [a.reshape(shape),None],
                    flags = ['multi_index','refs_ok'],
                    op_flags = [['readonly'],
                                ['writeonly','allocate']],
                    op_dtypes = [object, float],
                    itershape = (shape)
                  )
    while not it.finished:
        ind = it.multi_index
        it.operands[1][ind] = it.operands[0][ind].foo()
        it.iternext()
    return it.operands[1]

def sol1():
    return evaluate_and_reshape(a,(20,5))

def sol2():
    return np.reshape( [o.foo() for o in a.flat], (20,5) )
```

Timing:

```
timeit sol1()
#10000 loops, best of 3: 110 us per loop
timeit sol2()
#10000 loops, best of 3: 54.8 us per loop
```